# Execute SQL file in Snowflake through Snowsight Editor

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the Snowsight Query Editor. Is there any option to run multiple queries or a execute sql file?

Tried to use snowsql command which couldnot help

Answer (score 0):

In Snowsight UI worksheets, You can run multiple queries by selecting the queries and clicking the run button.[Run button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u12D.png)

To execute all the queries in the worksheet, click on the 'drop-down arrow' and select 'Run All'.

---

To execute a script SQL file in snowsight UI, click on the menu image next to your worksheet name and then click on the option 'Import SQL from file'.
[screenshot showing the 'import SQL from file' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8S1v.png)